# How to improve the visibility of the line numbers in Material theme?

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, sublimetext

By default the contrast of the line numbers in this theme is very low.
How can we modify the color of the line numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Edit the rule in the theme package

1. To be able to edit the package, we need to install **PackageResourceViewer**:

   - In the Command Palette (*Tools>Command Palettes...*), enter `Package Control: Install Package`
   - Search for "PackageResourceViewer"
2. Since PackageResourceViewer is installed, we can now override the rule:

   - In the Command Palette (*Tools>Command Palettes...*), enter `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
   - Go to *Material Theme>schemes>Material-Theme-tmTheme* (if you are using the default theme of Material Theme)
   - Find all the keys named `gutterForeground` and replace the string value by #4b5960